# NodeJS - How to create a desktop app that is just launching the server locally (without creating a desktop browser)

Tags: node.js, server, desktop-application

I've written a NodeJS app with ExpressJS that creates a web server (which is basically fetching SDMX data and send it back in html).

I want to create a desktop app so that users can double-click on it and have access to the web server by going on http://localhost:8080.

Basically, the app would install nodeJS and do `node server.js`.
I do no want to create a desktop-browser (with Electron and the like) since the web-app is not to be used directly but rather via http request in a statistical software (EViews, R, Matlab).

I didn't find any ways to do it. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: This question seems a bit confusing to me, but maybe it's a straightforward solution:  would just running the app in the background and creating a shortcut to that address be what you're looking for?  Or are you looking for one of those all in one solutions that package up the server and frontend code into a packaged app so that is appears like a regular desktop app?  I'd have a separate script that starts whatever you need for it to run, and have that start on login or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to avoid users to (i) install nodejs on their computer manually, (ii) open the command line and type node server.js. My preferred solution would be indeed an app that runs in the background so that opening a web browser and typing http://localhost:8080 connects you to the server. But how could I achieve that ?

Comment: Just create a bash script that installs it on the server so you don't have to do much to install on new PC.  Or docker images are good for that.  I'd have the server on a separate PC from the clients but that really depends on what you need.   Theres some Linux directory or file that will run everything on login but I forget which so on boot the process will run. Maybe create a watch and reboot it if the process crashes via a daemon.  You can also write in /etc/hosts to point it to your ip when given a hostname to give it a proper name.